# Filter property of openfiledialog not working

Tags: c#, filter, file-extension, openfiledialog

i am close to finishing a brainfuck ide for my c# project in school. one of the problems nagging me is that the filter of the openfiledialog does not work when i try to open a .b code file. i save a file with the extension .b in notepad, then i try to open it with the ide. only problem ist, when i choose *.b-Files from the extension dropdown, i dont get any files displayed, just folders. when i choose to display any file, it works fine.

any ideas? here is my method for opening the file:

```
public void oeffnenDatei()
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog ();
    ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    ofd.Multiselect = false;
    ofd.Filter = "Brainscramble-Dateien (*.b) | *.b | Alle Dateien (*.*)|*.*";
    if ( ofd.ShowDialog () == DialogResult.OK )
    {
        addTab ( ofd.SafeFileName );
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader ( ofd.FileName );                
        setCode ( reader.ReadToEnd () );
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have a space after the extension `*.b` in the filter property
This will work

```
ofd.Filter = "Brainscramble-Dateien (*.b)|*.b|Alle Dateien (*.*)|*.*";
```

Curiously, the space in front is not a problem

Comment: +1 i had a similar problem here: `saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel file (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx |All files (*.*)|*.*";`. It worked after i've removed the space in `*.xlsx `. I don't know why this question was downvoted (+1 also).

Comment: My OpenFileDialog was not filtering. I had OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "*". I changed it to OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "". Now OpenFileDialog1 is filtering as expected.